# Header Content Type in axios can't set application/json

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to configure headers in a project with `vue.js` and `axios` to call a service that expects a json. My problem is that when I make my call with the `POST` method, `axios` puts to the request `Content-Type` header with `x-www-urlencoded`, but in my code, I put manually `Content-Type` header with `application / json`.

```
var loginObj = {
    var1: payload.login,
    var2: payload.password
}

const jsonLogin = JSON.stringify(loginObj)

const config = {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
}

axios({
    url: 'url/example',
    method: 'post',
    data: jsonLogin,
    config
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) property to set header config should be `headers:` and you are setting with `config:`
try with:

```
axios({
    url: 'url/example',
    method: 'post',
    data: jsonLogin,
    headers: config.headers
  })
```

or change your const config to:

```
const configHeaders = {
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json"
};
```

and use it with:

```
axios({
  url: "url/example",
  method: "post",
  data: jsonLogin,
  headers: configHeaders
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My solution was to install the qs library and convert the object into json with qs.stringify when it is sent.


axios.post('url/example',
        qs.stringify(loginObj),
        headers
      )